# What about writing a large data volume at 70.000 records/second?

Tags: mysql, parallel-processing, volume

Perhaps someone can share an opinion on this? I'm currently looking into a solution to storing between 500 million and 4 billion records per day into a single (or 2) table(s) in a database with a minimum writing rate of 70.000 records/second. A record contains roughly 30 variables. We want to load data hourly and in parallel (data is partitioned) up to the machines maximum capacity in terms of CPU, memory and IO. During writing, queries must be possible and they should remain acceptably performant during write operations.

I've been browsing the web to see if others have attempted parallel writing these quantities to a MySQL db but have not found anything specific. Most look at transactions per second, but that is not what we're dealing with here. We're loading raw data and we need to do it fast, in parallel and with zero downtime (ie users must be able to query what's available). Is it worth looking into MySQL to do this job or should we not even consider it if we're not spending a HUGE amount (what do you reckon?) on hardware?

Note: Diskspace is no issue with SAN storage via GBit FC available in a multicore 64bit 128GB server. I'm not looking for detailed technical solutions, rather feasibility from an expert's point of view with perhaps a few hints/tips to point me in the right direction.

Appreciate your insights.

---

In response to comments:

Each record counts individually and each variable is a possible candidate search criterion. More info:

- yesterday's and older data (up to 10d) has to be queryable (SQL would be great for it's simple)
- Data access preferably not through a custom API, much rather prefer an open standard like ODBC or a client (such as the Oracle Client)
- Data consumption involves summarization (after midnight and partially also every hour where stats concern min/max/avg) and storage in higher level history tables for end-user reporting. That and the earlier mentioned searching of the raw data for problem/adhoc analysis.
- It needs to be easy to drop a full day's worth of data at the end of the 10 day cycle.
- Just to highlight it once more: writing takes places every hour to keep up with the delivery and not create a backlog for midnight summaries cannot be postponed for long.
- Search results don't need to be instant, but should preferably not exceed +- 15 minutes on the entire 10 day volume = 300 billion records.

Comment: Maybe you should ask this at serverfault.com

Comment: Cheers, I'll have a look there too.

Comment: Is that 4 billion a day a one off or you plan to use such a system for years to come? A single server won't cut it here, nor will regular db setup. You'll have to split reads and writes via proxying, but the setup would have to be such that you have a dedicated machine for handling only a portion of the whole data set. It sounds like either a lot of custom work or you should take a look at Hadoop - a Map/Reduce framework for distributed computing.

Comment: The question includes  .....
 solution to storing between 500 million and 4 billion records per day into a single (or 2) table(s) in a database with a minimum writing rate of 70.000 records/second.   If we agree there are exactly 86,400 seconds in a day, to store 4 billion rows a day will require writing rate of more than 46,000 rows/records per second.  How was 70 writes per second computed?

Answer (score 2):

With that amount of data I think you should try looking into NoSQL (MongoDB, Cassandra, HBase, etc.). With MySQL you have to scale your servers a lot. We tried doing ~1200 inserts/sec and MySQL failed (or hardware failed). The solution was using XCache (memcached failed at that time also). Try looking into NoSQL, you'll like it.

Comment: Thank you. That gives me 3 solutions to investigate and it also adds weight to the no-go I received internally with regards to MySQL.

Comment: i agree with you @donis, with this amount of data 'relational databases' aren't appropriated, Cassandra, NoSQL are more recommended though.

Comment: @MArtin - there are other solutions: if you use PHP - you can cache your data using XCache (because it has cache listing functions), then with a background job dump them to MySQL. It depends if you need your data immediately or it can wait a bit. Give us more info - maybe the answers will be more clearer.

Comment: NoSQL doesn't have transaction support. If it's required that each record is actually written - NoSQL won't cut it. There's also the issue of searching and using the data, that part wasn't mentioned at all. A dataset of such volume is difficult to search, especially if you need to use all 30 variables mentioned as conditions.

Comment: @Michael J.V. Some NoSQL solutions will allow you to require that the data be written. See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/getLastError+Command

Answer (score 1):

4B rows x 30 x 4 bytes is about 1/2 terabyte a day.  I don't think you're going to be able to keep this in a single machine and your SAN may have trouble too.  I would look at Cassandra as it's built for high write volumes.

Comment: Actually we have 35TB ready to go. I'

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd separate the solution into data capture and data analysis servers; this is a fairly common pattern. Queries and reporting run against your data warehouse (where you may be able to use a different schema to your data collection system). You load data into your data warehouse using an ETL (extract, transform, load) process, which in your case could be very simple.

As to how you would support 70K writes per second - I'd say this is well beyond the capabilities of most RDBMS servers unless you have a dedicated team and infrastructure. It's not something you want to be learning on the job.

NoSQL seems a better match.

Comment: It's not beyond capabilities of RDBMS servers if you don't need transactions. It's also achievable if you use Fusion IO drives, you get to have fast writes, transactions and all the other beautiful things RDBMS offers and NoSQLs don't.

Comment: Yeah, that's what the "unless" point it's about. You can do it, but it's a pretty specialized area of expertise.

Comment: Dedicated hardware is a must I read. I wrote it down. We may have 6 out of 16 cpus available on our AIX servers for just the mysql processing. I believe I ought to request a MySql DBA to test this with us and see where the boundaries are and if they can be shifted. Thanks all.